# Zeros of linear partial fractions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems

I am trying to find some general properties of the zeros of

$P(z) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\alpha_i}{z+z_i}$,

with $\sum_{i} \alpha_i = 0$, $z_i \in [-M\; 0], i=1,\ldots,n$ and all $\alpha_i$ and $z_i$ are real, and $M<\infty$.

Actually, what I really hope to find is that the real part of the zeros lie in the same interval as the poles, i.e., in the interval $[-M \; 0]$.

This problem arises in a particular type of dynamic systems over graphs.  The function $P(z)$ is the transfer-function of a linear system running a consensus protocol, so the poles of the system are the eigenvalues of the combinatorial Laplacian.

Thanks!

Comment: The poles are $-z_i\in[0,M]$, not in $[-M,0]$. Or did you want to write `$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\alpha_i}{z-z_i}$`?

Comment: Hi Emil,

Yes, you are correct.  $z_i \in [0, \; M]$ and the poles of the system are therefore in the interval $[-M, \; 0]$.

Comment: I received a couple comments (that appear deleted now) that suggest the Gauss-Lucas theorem might be applicable.

I guess this is not the case, as the constants $\alpha_i$ are not integer (and may not even be rational).

Are there any generalizations of the Gauss-Lucas theorem that can handle this case?

Comment: Sorry that was my comment earlier, and I deleted it because as you say it doesn't answer the question. I somehow read the condition as $\alpha_i\geq 0$. I think that by approximating $\alpha_i$ by rationals and rescaling makes it safe to assume that they are integers, bu this doesn't help as the only case I know how to put any sort of bound on the roots of $P$ is when $\sum \alpha_i \neq 0$.

Comment: Dan, are you still here? Does my answer of 27 February meet the specifications, or did I miss the point? 

Comment: Hi Gerry, Sorry for the delay.

Yes, your solution does provide a counter example for the problem as I stated.  I guess, however, that my problem has more structure.
For example, the poles $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of the graph Laplacian, and therefore $\lambda_1=0$.  Secondly, the constants $\alpha_i$ come from the eigenvectors of the Laplacian.  In particular, given 2 nodes $r$ and $q$ in the graph (which are fixed), and the eigenvectors of the the Laplacian $u_k$, then $\alhpa_i = u_{i,r}u_{i,q}$ (where $u_{i,r}$ corresponds to the r-th element of the eigenvector $u_i$).

Comment: I imagine $\lambda_1=0$ can be accommodated by considering $(1/z)+(-2/(z+9))+(1/(z+19))$. I don't know about the constraints on the $\alpha_i$. Maybe if you post a new question with all the constraints spelled out (and with a reference to the current question) someone will have an idea. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${1\over z+1}+{-2\over z+10}+{1\over z+20}={170-z\over(z+1)(z+10)(z+20)}$$ seems to satisfy your conditions with $n=3$ and $M=20$ but the zero at 170 is not in the same interval as the poles.